# Stanford NLP (NER modelling) - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Argument array lengths differ

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have searched and tried to work on this issue for quite some time (around 4 days) before coming here. I'm trying to train a swedish NER-tagged corpus. I got the test data and train data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/andreasklintberg/swedish-ner-corpus/version/1#).

Here is the error I get, when I try to train the model

`\project\stanford_ner>java -mx1000m -cp stanford-ner.jar;lib/* 
    edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop train/train_properties.txt
    Invoked on Tue Sep 25 10:44:13 IST 2018 with arguments: -prop 
    train/train_properties.txt
    usePrevSequences=true
    useClassFeature=true
    useTypeSeqs2=true
    useSequences=true
    wordShape=chris2useLC
    useTypeySequences=true
    useDisjunctive=true
    noMidNGrams=true
    serializeTo=dummy_ner_model_swede.ser.gz
    maxNGramLeng=6
    useNGrams=true
    usePrev=true
    useNext=true
    maxLeft=1
    trainFile=train/dummy_swede_corpus.tsv
    map=word=0,answer=1
    useWord=true
    useTypeSeqs=true
    Error on line 85124: bn
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Argument 
    array lengths differ: [class 
    edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation, class 
    edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation] vs. [bn]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.initFromStrings(CoreLabel.java:263)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.(CoreLabel.java:150)`

**The error I'm trying to point out is**

:
    `Error on line 85124: bn`

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Argument array lengths differ: [class 
    edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation, class 
    edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation] vs. [bn]`

I do not undersdtand what is "bn" here. I did go through the implementation of the code from [github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreLabel.java), but to no avail. If I use all train data until before that line of error, I am able to train the data and get the model.

And on the line of error, I don't see anything special. It's just another word with NER tag as mentioned in the feature list of properties file.

Comment: Did you later resolve this issue?

Comment: Nope! I created my own tsv file afresh